# XSLT can't handle entity

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a XML- String and i'am trying to remove all empty XML-Tags and whitespaces.
For that i'am using the following XSL-Sheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(*) and not(text()[normalize-space()])]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My input String XML is for example:

```
String s = "<main>           <test>123öü aksdjf0192301ß09aasdfg   0</test>            <test> </test>  <test>12031</test>"

             + "\n" +

             "<test>" + "</test>" + "</main>";
```

For the XSL Transformation i'am using the following Java code:

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlContent);
  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
  TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(
     "style.xsl"));
  transformer.transform(new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(reader),
     new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(writer));
  String result = writer.toString();
```

My Output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><main><test>123öü aksdjf0192301ß09aasdfg   0</test><test>12031</test></main>
```

That's exactly my expected result but when i add an entity for example **'&'** to my Input string the transformation fails.

With the error:  **The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.**

How can i solve that Problem? And is XSL the correct why to implement a functionality like this?

I expect this Output:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><main><test>123öü aksdjf0192301ß09aasdfg   0</test><test>120>&& | 31</test></main>
```

With this Input:

```
 String s = "<main>           <test>123öü aksdjf0192301ß09aasdfg   0 >&& |  </test>            <test> </test>  <test>120>&& | 31</test>"

                 + "\n" +

                 "<test>" + "</test>" + "</main>";
```

Comment: When you add `&` the compiler think you are trying to reference an entity. If you simply want to add the character then simply add `&amp;`

Comment: Don't try to build XML with string concatenation, use JDOM or DOM or similar, that way you won't run into problems with malformed XML causing errors later on in the tool chain where an application expects XML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ampersand (`&`) isn't a legal character on its own, you'll have to encode it as `&amp;`.

From the [XML Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax):

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) must not appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they must be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings  `&amp;`  and `&lt;`  respectively.

Comment: Thank You. Do you have any suggestion to do the encoding after the XML-String is created?